# Updating Multiple MySQL Rows at Once

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the scenario:

When the customer first place his/her order, the table is empty; looks like this

```
+----+------+---------+
| no | item | results |
+----+------+---------+
```

When the order has been placed, the table looks like this

```
+----+--------+---------+
| no | item   | results |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | Test 1 | null    |
| 2  | Test 2 | null    |
| 3  | Test 3 | null    |
+----+--------+---------+
```

That's the easy part. I can use comma separated `VALUE` clauses in the `INSERT` query.

The order is then sent to the lab, and when the lab guys are done with the job, the table becomes like this:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| no | item   | results |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | Test 1 | Res 1   |
| 2  | Test 2 | Res 2   |
| 3  | Test 3 | Res 3   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

This is where your answers come in. I need to update the tests with the results. However I'd really prefer not to do dozens of `UPDATE--SET--WHERE` statements, one for each test items. Is there any other way?

Comment: You need to loop each values for update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on storage engine restrictions etc you could use *insert on duplicate*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

This allows you to use a insert query that updates values if the rows already exist.

Something like

```
insert into table (no, item, result) values(1, "A", "B") on duplicate key update item=values(item), result=values(result)
```

There is also *REPLACE INTO*.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

One of these should fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another table and `INSERT` values into it:

```
+----+---------+
| no | results |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Res 1   |
| 2  | Res 2   |
| 3  | Res 3   |
+----+---------+
```

And then just one update:

```
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    results = t2.results
INNER JOIN
    t2
ON t1.no = t2.no
```

Comment: This is **genius**!
However, genius workarounds tend to come with some downfall or unforeseen consequence. I'd like to wait around and see what others come up with.

Comment: Spawning new tables every time a result is to be updated might not be very efficient. You COULD do this and then merge the changes back into your primary table or even kill off and replace you main table with this new one and keep doing that. But that defiantly won't be less work than a loop and several UPDATE statements. Also, doing this or anything more complicated than *REPLACE INTO* or *ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE* would probably be best fitted to do in a stored procedure. That could take the *no*s and *result*s as arguments.

Comment: This approach is not spawning. I mean create table only once.
Assume that main table has many columns. INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in this case will take more efforts from server because there are many UPDATE queries will be generated. If you insert all result values once into helper table it will be only one INSERT query (faster that many UPDATEs) and only one UPDATE query that will use all the Power of joins ;)

Comment: Ahhh sorry m8. I scrolled to quick and missread one of the initial table declarations for your one. And since I read the question as this being something that could occur more than once I felt it could be a bit of work. Having only the results in it's own table is quite nice. Only question is how that table will be generated and who will do it. Might be more work than just looping and updating. But if he could get the lab to supply this table this would be a done deal. But if he only receives a list of id's and results it might be an extra step to first create this result table.

Comment: You can create table once when you generate whole schema and then only `TRUNC` table after every UPDATE.

Comment: Yea, but you have to get the new result data into it each time before joining the results into the primary table. That's what I meant. You of course do not have to drop it each time ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Table must have a Unique Key. It is faster than single rows updating.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (to my knowledge), you can't do multiple unique updates in a single SQL query.

You can update multiple rows in a single query, but they will each get the same updates applied to them.

Each update needs to be done as its own statement.

Your best bet would be to write a loop that updates a single row, and have it run for each update that needs to be done.

Comment: This is true for the *UPDATE* statement. But using INSERT with ON *DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE* or *REPLACE INTO* you can indeed "update" several existing rows in one query.